# FadeIn/out effect on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout

I have a FadeIn/Out effect on my page for a couple of Social logos.

It seems they work fine but the initial fade in wont work untill i hover over them.

How can i make the fade in function work when the page is loaded?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("img.a").hover(function() 
        {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast");
        },
        function() 
        {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.5"}, "fast");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The Page:

> www.tranceil.fm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the CSS already once the document is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.a").css({"opacity": "0.5"});
    $("img.a").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.5"}, "fast");
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I know you need a jQuery solution but why to use it if you can do it with CSS?

```
img.class {
   opacity: .5;
   transition: opacity 2s;
   /* Transitions will take care of the smooth effect */
   -moz-transition: opacity 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
   -webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transition: opacity 2s; /* Opera */
}

img.class:hover {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Note: Am not using `rgba` because it is just an image

For IE support you can use [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/)

If you still want to stick to jQuery, am not that good with it but I guess you can set initial opacity for your social icon by simply defining it in your CSS

```
img.a {
   opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: +1 same thing I (was) writing, no need to use extra js when it's not needed.

Comment: @user1394965 ya I also added transitions for a smooth effect

Comment: that's not animated... You'd at least need to add `transition`... And it also won't work in browsers like IE8...

Comment: this is not a fadein/fadeout. it just change opacity without interpolation

Comment: Well thats the solution i came across when i searched for the effect..but yours seems simpler :) thank you, ill keep it in mind for next time!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.a").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.5"}, "fast");
        }
    ).css('opacity':'0.5');

});
</script>
```

You can do it with CSS too but jQuery is a little more browser-safe.